# Show that $\lim_{t -> \infty} V(t)$ exists and is finite for non-increasing function $V(t)$, $V(t) \geq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose that $V:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is non-increasing and that $V(t) \geq 0$  for all $t \geq 0$.

Show that $\lim_{t -> \infty} V(t)$ exists and is finite.

Not sure how to approach this question. If someone can point me in a direction (stuff to read, videos or similar), I would be very grateful. The questions is from a course where I'm lacking some prerequisite knowledge.

I've done some reading on infimum/supremum and lower/upper bounds.

*Edit:*

I guess since $V(t)$ is non-increasing, $V(t_n) \leq V(t_m)$, where $t_n > t_m$.

As $t \rightarrow \infty$, it makes sense that $V(t)$ must reach the region of its greatest lower bound, the infimum. I assume a more mathematical formulation is required. I'm also a bit confused about the information given. What does the fact that $V(t) \geq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$ suggest?

Comment: You can check a similar question for your doubt https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581282/help-with-a-theorem-about-continuous-increasing-functions

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

A bounded below real set has a lower bound. Prove that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} V(t) =\inf \{V(t) \mid t \ge 0\}$: the lower bound is the limit.

Comment: Thanks! I found some material thanks to your formulation. I will get back to the question once I've done some reading.

Comment: I guess since $V(t)$ is non-increasing, $V(t_n) \leq V(t_m)$, where $t_n > t_m$. 

As $t \rightarrow \infty$, it makes sense that $V(t)$ must reach the region of its greatest lower bound, the infimum. I assume a more mathematical formulation is required. I'm also a bit confused about the information given. What does the fact that $V(t) \geq 0$ for all $t \geq 0$ suggest?

Comment: Since V(t) is nonnegative, the image of V is bounded below (by zero), so that it has an infimum. Then use the hint given in the answer.

Comment: I understand. But I don't understand how to prove it. What can I search to read up on this?

Comment: @Rob Best would be take an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof using the definition of a limit.

Comment: Thanks. I think that the fact that the function is non-increasing is confusing me also. I'll see what I find

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere. Is the idea that at some point, $V(t)$ will converge because it is bounded below. And this will also be it's infimum. There is no reason this has to be zero, right? $V(t) \geq 0$ is only to inform that it is bounded below?